# Proguard error when adding dependency to Jetpack Compose desktop application

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, okhttp

I created a new desktop compose app. It can run locally and `gradle createReleaseDistributable` is successful.

Then I defined a library dependency.

**build.gradle.kts**

```
dependencies {
  implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
  implementation(libs.nostrino) // added
}
```

**gradle/libs.versions.toml**

```
[versions]
nostrino = "0.0.3"

[libraries]
nostrino = { module = "app.cash.nostrino:nostr-sdk", version.ref = "nostrino" }

[plugins]
```

The `Main.kt` still runs locally, but `gradle createReleaseDistributable` complains:

```
Warning: there were 109 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass)
```

The unresolved classes are exclusively from the `okhttp3.internal` package.

```
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.android.AndroidLog: can't find referenced class android.util.Log
Warning: okhttp3.internal.platform.android.BouncyCastleSocketAdapter: can't find referenced class org.bouncycastle.jsse.BCSSLSocket
+ 107 more
```

okhttp is a [transitive dependency of the newly added library](https://github.com/cashapp/nostrino/blob/main/lib/build.gradle.kts#L18).

What's going on here and what is the right way to resolve it?